# Flutter-Firebase firestore: How can I return the user's name from his id

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase firestoreUi to display my news queue and all is ok, but what I would like is that instead of displaying the id of the user who publishes the news, that his name be displayed in the RichText.
I'm really stuck and don't know what to do.
Your help is really welcome, here is my code in its entirety:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterfire_ui/firestore.dart';
import 'package:flyzik/models/post_model.dart';
import 'package:flyzik/services/db_service.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
import 'package:shimmer/shimmer.dart';
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeago;

import '../constants.dart';
import '../size_config.dart';

class ActualiteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ActualiteWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ActualiteWidget> createState() => _ActualiteWidgetState();
}

class _ActualiteWidgetState extends State<ActualiteWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    timeago.setLocaleMessages('fr_short', timeago.FrShortMessages());
    return FirestoreListView<PostModel>(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      loadingBuilder: (context) => dummyListActu(),
      errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) =>
          dummyCustomError(error, stackTrace),
      pageSize: 10,
      query: DBServices().getActualites,
      itemBuilder: (context, snapshot) {
        PostModel actu = snapshot.data();
        return Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.black12,
                    width: 1.5,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              width: 40,
                              height: 40,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                      image: NetworkImage(actu.imagePost!),
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                RichText(
                                  text: TextSpan(
                                    text: "${actu.user_id!}",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey[900],
                                        fontSize:
                                            getProportionateScreenWidth(12),
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        letterSpacing: 1),
                                  ),
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 3,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "${timeago.format(DateTime.parse("${DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(actu.createAt!)}"), locale: 'fr_short')}",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(10),
                                      color: Colors.grey),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                        text: actu.description!,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(10),
                            color: Colors.grey[800],
                            height: 1.5,
                            letterSpacing: .7),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 200,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(actu.imagePost!),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: (() => print("LIKE")),
                          child: makeLikeButton(isActive: true),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            right: 10,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            makeLike(),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 5,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "2.5K",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(10),
                                  color: Colors.grey[800]),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the structure of your data, so you either:

- Save the whole user inside the `PostModel`, so it will be something like:

  ```
  { 
    imagePost: ...,  
    createAt:'time',  
    description: 'description',  
    user:{  
      id:123,
      name:'UserName'  
      }  
   }
  ```
- Or keep only the user id, but then you have to get the user info from the users' collection, which of course you must have

Comment: No way I already have several data described

Comment: Then please provide your structure, or where exactly the username exists

Comment: The usernames are in another firestore collection

Comment: Then in that case you have to use the second way, where in `PostModel` you save the user id, and when you get the `PostModel` in your app, you get the user from its collection by its id...... This way is better if you want the user information to be updated everywhere in your collections, but that would cast making more reads to the firebase... for more details take a look at this https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/ to understand different structures, also do look online about Firestore Denormalization & normalization